# Replace all the occurrence of a string

Tags: c#, strings, .net

I have the following function to replace all the occurrence of a string that matches certain token.

```
public string ReplaceTokenBySample(string StingValue)
{
    List<Token> tokens = GetTokenList();
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        StingValue = StingValue.Replace(token.Token, token.SampleValue);
    }
    return StingValue;
}
```

`GetTokenList();` will return

```
Token                   SampleValue 
##Username##            John Doe    
##UserEmail##           john.doe@domain.com 
##UserFirstName##       John    
##UserLastName##        Doe
```

How can I optimize this code?

Full console app code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Token
    {
        public string TokenValue { get; set; }
        public string SampleValue { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public List<Token>GetTokenList()
        {
            List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>
            {
                new Token(){ TokenValue = "##Username##", SampleValue="John Doe" },
                new Token(){ TokenValue = "##UserEmail##", SampleValue="john.doe@domain.com " },
                new Token(){ TokenValue = "##UserFirstName##", SampleValue="John" },
                new Token(){ TokenValue = "##UserLastName##", SampleValue="Doe"}
            };
            return tokens;
        }

        public string ReplaceTokenBySample(string StringValue)
        {
            List<Token> tokens = GetTokenList();
            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                StringValue = StringValue.Replace(token.TokenValue, token.SampleValue);
            }
            return StringValue;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            string StringValue ="Hello ##Username##! I have emailed you at ##UserEmail##. ##UserFirstName## ##UserLastName## how is you days going on. Have a good day ##Username##. ";
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ReplaceTokenBySample(StringValue));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this token system if `ReplaceTokenBySample` doesn't allow you to pass in your own tokens?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet token and sample value will be stored on database. And here StingValue will be replace by Mail Template. User are allowed to create any number of token..

Comment: That's not what the code you have shown is doing, however. If you're planning to modify `GetTokenList`, then `ReplaceTokenBySample` is limited to always use whatever tokens are returned by `GetTokenList`. If, instead, you pass tokens in as an argument, then you can reuse the replacement logic in different contexts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Loops can sometimes be so ugly. You can get rid of them completely and use `Regex` instead. It'll replace the placeholders one by one without scanning the string from the beginning each time. Just put your placeholder and the corresponding values in a dictionary and let `Regex.Replace` do the job.

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["Username"] = "John Doe",
    ["UserEmail"] = "john.doe@domain.com",
    ["UserFirstName"] = "John",
    ["UserLastName"] = "Doe"
};

var value = "Hello ##Username##! I have emailed you at ##UserEmail##. ##UserFirstName## ##UserLastName## how is you days going on. Have a good day ##Username##. ";

var pattern = $"##(?<placeholder>{string.Join("|", replacements.Keys)})##";
var result = Regex.Replace(value, pattern, m => replacements[m.Groups["placeholder"].Value], RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Comment: I always forget regex...this should perform pretty well and it's also really readable!!!

Comment: Hi @t3chb0t would it be costly to convert list to dictionary? Because list is return from database.

Comment: @KiranShahi there is no general answer to this question. It depends on many factors: how long is the list? how long are the strings? how many of them you are processing per second/minute/hour? It doesn't have to be a dictionary. You can look the values up in the list with `.Single` but agian... it depends on many many different factors.

Comment: @t3chb0t is there any way to use the answer you have mention with list? Actually I don't want loop as well as type conversion

Comment: @KiranShahi sure, you can use `.Select` to get placeholder names and `.Single[OrDefault]` to get the values.

Comment: @t3chb0t is `(?<` the part of regex ? My function return string enclosed by `##` so I have changed my function to `var pattern = $"(?<placeholder>{string.Join("|", replacements.Keys)})";` is this correct ? Currently it is working fine as expected.

Comment: @KiranShahi exactly... when it's working then you've implemented it correctly ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80111/discussion-between-kiran-shahi-and-t3chb0t).

Answer (score 13):

If this is your real use-case then I'd not go beyond the *obvious* optimizations. In this case you're creating a new string for each replacement, you can use `StringBuilder.Replace()` instead:

```
public string ReplaceTokenBySample(string value)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(value);
    GetTokenList().ForEach(x => result.Replace(x.TokenValue, x.SampleValue));

    return result.ToString();
}
```

If instead of `List<Token>` you have `IEnumerable<Token>` (or if you want to avoid `List<T>.ForEach()`) then you can use:

```
public string ReplaceTokenBySample(string value)
{
    GetTokenList().Aggregate(new StringBuilder(value),
        (result, item) => result.Replace(item.TokenValue, item.SampleValue));

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Few things to consider:

- You're performing ordinal case-sensitive comparison, it seems to be appropriate to replace *placeholders* with their actual value and it has the benefit to be reasonably fast. If this is not the case then you should definitely go with [t3schb0t's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/198377/13424) (which handles this properly and it's incredibly more readable.)
- Parameters should be camelCase.
- It's usually confusing to overwrite parameters value with something else (especially for non trivial code), compiler is able to optimize your code to get the best of it even when using a local variable.

Few more notes about overall design: you do not validate your parameters anywhere, if they're only used internally to your assembly then mark them `internal` or `private` (as appropriate) and ASSERT about their content (for example: why do you declare `Token` as `public`?)

Names sound little bit strange, you do not need to repeat the type in the name: `TokenSample` and `TokenValue` inside the `Token` class (and `StringValue` for a value of type `String`).

If you intend to fill `Token` programmatically then adding a `Token(string, string)` ctor may help to keep your code shorter.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @AdrianoRepetti I have find answer by t3chb0t more suitable :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: @KiranShahi you welcome; unless you strictly need ordinal comparison then t3's answer should perform really well and it's much more readable.